# What is the difference between 2 methods with ref object par and without?

Tags: c#, ref

I wonder what the difference is between the following methods with regards to how the object parameter is referenced:

```
public void DoSomething(object parameter){}
```

and

```
public void DoSomething(ref object parameter){}
```

Should I use `ref object parameter` in cases where I want to change the reference to the `object` not override the object in the same reference?

Comment: RTM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public void DoSomething(object parameter)
{
  parameter = new Object(); // original object from the callee would be unaffected. 
}

public void DoSomething(ref object parameter)
{
  parameter = new Object(); // original object would be a new object 
}
```

See the article: [Parameter Passing in C# by Jon Skeet](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

In C#, Reference type object's address is passed by value, when the `ref` keyword is used then the original object can be assigned a new object or null, without `ref` keyword that is not possible.

Consider the following example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Object obj1 = new object();
        obj1 = "Something";

        DoSomething(obj1);
        Console.WriteLine(obj1);

        DoSomethingCreateNew(ref obj1);
        Console.WriteLine(obj1);

        DoSomethingAssignNull(ref obj1);
        Console.WriteLine(obj1 == null);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void DoSomething(object parameter)
    {
        parameter = new Object(); // original object from the callee would be unaffected. 
    }

    public static void DoSomethingCreateNew(ref object parameter)
    {
        parameter = new Object(); // original object would be a new object 
    }

    public static void DoSomethingAssignNull(ref object parameter)
    {
        parameter = null; // original object would be a null 
    }
}
```

Output would be:

```
Something
System.Object
True
```

Answer (score 2):

passing a variable by ref allows the function to repoint that variable to another object, or indeed null: e.g.

```
object parameter = new object();

FailedChangeRef(parameter); // parameter still points to the same object
ChangeRef(ref parameter); // parameter now points to null

public void FailedChangeRef(object parameter)
{
            parameter = null; // this has no effect on the calling variable
}

public void ChangeRef(ref object parameter)
{
            parameter = null;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Argument Passing ByVal:**
Describes passing arguments by value, which means the procedure cannot modify the variable itself.

**Argument Passing ByRef:**
Describes passing arguments by reference, which means the procedure can modify the variable itself.

Comment: But `objects` are passing in `c#` by reference by default.

Comment: unless you count the reference itself as being the value of an object?

Answer (score 0):

When you see `ref object` that means, argument has to be `object` type.

You can read in documentation:

> When a formal parameter is a reference parameter, the corresponding
>   argument in a method invocation must consist of the keyword ref
>   followed by a variable-reference (§5.3.3) of the same type as the
>   formal parameter. A variable must be definitely assigned before it can
>   be passed as a reference parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, the default mechanism of method arguments is **Pass by Value**. Hence if your are declaring a method like,

```
public void DoSomething(object parameter){} // Pass by value
```

So, a new copy of the object is created, so the changes on the parameter will not affect the original object passed in.

But, when u pass the parameter by ref, it is **Pass by Reference**

```
public void DoSomething(ref object parameter) // Pass by reference
```

Now, your are operating on the address on the originally passed object. Hence the changes u are making on the parameter inside the method will affect the original object.